# Bring Properties to the button in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mern

I am trying build an booking app in react, can anyone suggest how can I bring the properties from the table to the button?

For example:
when the user click the select button on the first schedule, the schedule id and the training id of the first row, will be bringing to the select button to perform action. Any tips and helps are much appreciated in advance!

[image]

rendering table:
**booking() is my action

```
const bookBtn=(trainer_id, schedule_id)=>{

    return(
        <Button onClick={booking(trainer_id,schedule_id)} variant="danger">
        Select
    </Button> 
    )
    
}
   const renderSchedule = (details, index) => {
    return (
        <tr key={index}>
            <td>{details._id}</td>
            <td>{details.trainer}</td>
            <td>{details.date}</td>
            <td>{details.startAt}</td>
            <td>{details.endAt}</td>
            <td>
             {bookBtn(details.trainer,details._id)}
            </td>
        </tr>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass a function to your `onClick` that invokes your custom handler with parameters:

```
const bookBtn = (trainer_id, schedule_id) => {
    return(
        <Button onClick={() => booking(trainer_id, schedule_id)} variant="danger">
            Select
        </Button> 
    );
}
```

If `booking` is indeed a handler, of course.